# How do I find the PublicKeyToken for a particular dll?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly, publickeytoken

I need to recreate a provider in my web.config file that looks something like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMemProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="TRAQDBConnectionString" applicationName="TRAQ" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         name="AspNetSqlMemProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"
    />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

However, I get a runtime error saying this assembly cannot be loaded, and I think it is because I have the wrong PublicKeyToken.  How do I look up the PublicKeyToken for my assembly?

Alternatively, am I going entirely the wrong way with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the PublicKeyToken of .Net assemblies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045033/getting-the-publickeytoken-of-net-assemblies)

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Using **PowerShell**, you can execute this statement:

```
([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\..\Full_Path\..\MyDLL.dll")).FullName
```

The output will provide the *Version*, *Culture* and *PublicKeyToken* as shown below:

```
MyDLL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a
```

Comment: Thanks! your method is the only one that worked for me sn -T dllname.dll would only show help text when I ran it

Comment: That's perfect! Avoids installing extra tools.

Comment: This is a way more easy to do it.

Comment: great! this works also when there is no PublicKeyToken available (ie. unsigned assemblies)

Comment: This is a more complete answer and covers more use cases. I needed it to refer to the the dll full name in code. Thanks!

Comment: In C# Interactive, you can call:

Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\some.dll").FullName);

Comment: Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013101B)"

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Annoyingly, PowerShell.exe keeps a lock on the dll even after the call completed. I needed to close the PowerShell console before I could build my solution again.

Comment: I don't know why PowerShell does not do any action when I call this command

Comment: My assembly has added to GAC, can I use just name?

Comment: **Warning**: You have to provide the **full** path. E.g. `([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\cf562e7e\7984a186\assembly\dl3\1e53bd22\00cb376e_eed8cf01\System.Web.Mvc.dll")).FullName`

Comment: Having to load a DLL to view its publickeytoken sounds risky. Is it possible to see the public key token via Nuget.org for example for the .NET ers out there ?

Comment: You have to use the correct version of Powershell (32bit or 64bit) based on the architecture of your dll. Otherwise you get an error `Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Test.dll' or one of its
dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)"`.

Answer (score 167):

Using [sn.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(VS.80).aspx) utility:

```
sn -T YourAssembly.dll
```

or loading the assembly in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: sn.exe can typically be found at one of the following locations under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Comment: Mind it, the key is case-sensitive. -t (lower case) will give the "Failed to convert key to token -- Invalid assembly public key.", which will send you searching in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 42):

If you have the DLL added to your project, you can open the csproj file and see the Reference tag.

Example:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Answer (score 26):

`sn -T <assembly>` in Visual Studio command line.
If an assembly is installed in the global assembly cache, it's easier to go to `C:\Windows\assembly` and find it in the list of GAC assemblies.

On your specific case, you might be mixing type full name with assembly reference, you might want to take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htw9h4z3.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

Answer is very simple use the .NET Framework tools `sn.exe`. So open the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt and then point to the dll’s folder you want to get the public key,

Use the following command,

```
sn –T myDLL.dll
```

This will give you the public key token. Remember one thing this only works if the assembly has to be strongly signed.

Example

```
C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>sn -T EdmGen.exe

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 3.5.21022.8
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Public key token is b77a5c561934e089
```

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2013 and you can't find "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" go have a look here how to fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22702405/187650

Comment: Note that this tool does not come with Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I use Windows Explorer, navigate to C:\Windows\assembly , find the one I need.  From the Properties you can copy the PublicKeyToken.

This doesn't rely on Visual Studio or any other utilities being installed.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding more info, I wasn't able to find sn.exe utility in the mentioned locations, in my case it was in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin

Comment: If you open up a visual studio command prompt it should be on your path.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045033/getting-the-publickeytoken-of-net-assemblies

Answer (score 3):

> Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\system.data.dll").FullName

Will result in

> System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Answer (score 3):

If you want the token for something published on NuGet,

For example, OxyPlot.Wpf :

https://nuget.info/packages/OxyPlot.Wpf/2.1.0

and browse for the dll and its details.

Just change the nuget pkg name and version on the url for any other package.

Answer (score 2):

The top answer from [danielB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24136074/8354765) works, but PowerShell will put a lock on the file until you close PowerShell completely.

An alternative is to read in the bytes of the .dll and use `load()` instead of `loadfile()`:

```
([system.reflection.assembly]::load([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\..\Full_Path\..\MyDLL.dll"))).FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

As @CRice said you can use the below method to get a list of dependent assembly with publicKeyToken

```
public static int DependencyInfo(string args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(Assembly.LoadFile(args).FullName);
    Console.WriteLine(Assembly.LoadFile(args).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault());
    try {
        var assemblies = Assembly.LoadFile(args).GetReferencedAssemblies(); 

        if (assemblies.GetLength(0) > 0)
        {
            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - " + assembly.FullName + ", ProcessorArchitecture=" + assembly.ProcessorArchitecture);             
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", e.Message);
        return 1;
    } 
    finally{}

    return 1;
}
```

i generally use it as a *LinqPad* script 
you can call it as

`DependencyInfo("@c:\MyAssembly.dll");` from the code

Answer (score 1):

put into file `dll-assemblyinfo` in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/sh

f=$(readlink -f "$1")

{
echo "using System.Reflection;"
echo "Assembly.LoadFile(\"$f\");"
} | csharp
```

chmod +x then

```
$ dll-assemblyinfo packages/System.Buffers.4.5.1/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Buffers.dll
System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
```

Comment: I'd love to use this! How do I find or install csharp?

Comment: `sudo apt install mono-csharp-shell`
 ### see also 
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/

Comment: Oh! Got it. Yeah, I thought you were using MSYS2 (or WSL) on Windows, and that csharp had been installed somewhere by the Visual Studio installer. Context is _so_ important! :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can also check by following method.

Go to Run : type the path of DLL for which you need public key.
You will find 2 files :
1. __AssemblyInfo_.ini
2. DLL file

Open this __AssemblyInfo_.ini file in notepad , here you can see Public Key Token.

Answer (score 0):

**For DLL generated by MSVC or others**
Using pktextract to get publicKeyToken from '.cer'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/pktextract-exe

See details from other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190473/12529885