# How to view public key tokens on DLL's

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know of a way to view the public key token on a DLL?  I'm investigating a possible mismatch between what is expected in code and what is being built.

Thanks in advance,
It Grunt

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().GetPublicKeyToken();
```

or

```
sn -T YourAssembly.dll
```

Answer (score 18):

`sn -Tp assembly.dll`

will tell you what you need to know

Comment: Thanks!! I got exactly what I was looking for! You get the approval for getting the first post in!

Answer (score 5):

I started using ILSpy, alternative for Reflector.NET. After opening dll, you can view public key token, version and more.

Answer (score 0):

For **DLL without .Net**, using pktextract to get `publicKeyToken`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/pktextract-exe

**Step1.** extract .cer from dll
Right click the file, select 'Properties' then 'Digital Signatures', you may see the certificate inside.
Then select one and choose 'View Certificate' -> 'Details' -> 'Copy to File'.

**Step2.** We assume the file is 'D:\test.cer', then using this tool to get the publicKeyToken.

```
C:\> pktextract D:\test.cer
Microsoft (R) Side-By-Side Public Key Token Extractor
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved

Certificate: "my-Test" - 2048 bits long
        publicKeyToken="ea1b32b5bee7776f"
```