# Running in VS2019 Admin Cmd window -- gacutil.exe error: "Failure adding assembly to the cache. The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-assembly, gac, gacutil

Running in VS2019 Admin Cmd window -- gacutil.exe error: "Failure adding assembly to the cache. The system cannot find the file specified."
GAC util path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil.exe`
Command line: `gacutil.exe  -i "DuraSysOrdFuncs.dll" -r FILEPATH "C:\Windows\DuraSysOrdFuncs.dll" ""`
I picked this version of GACUtil just because the C# library was built with a target framework of .Net 4.7.   It isn't clear to me that it much matters.
Doesn't matter what I put in the 3rd parameter of -r. Doesn't matter where I put my assembly on my local disk. Same error message.
I'm trying to put this in GAC because I need to call it from an SSIS package running on SQL Server 2016. I have opened Sysinternals ProcMon per a suggestion of @HansPassant in a different post. Not familiar with tool so haven't found the file location error. . . if that is the actual issue.

*Any input much appreciated*

Comment: Did you try passing a full path to the /i parameter?

Comment: That error would indicate to me that the specification of the DLL is wrong; that `gacutil` can't find `DuraSysOrdFuncs.dll`

Comment: Yes. You are both correct. I opened ProcMon after posting this and found an even indicating the DLL needing registration was being searched for in the path of the version of gacutil.exe that I was using.  I checked the GACUTIL help notes. Moving to fast and missed the part about the path. . . should have triple checked rather than posting. But thanks!  I'm glad others have posted. Very helpful resource, is StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, as the commenters noted, and as ProcMon indicates, is to just include the path for the .net assembly you're registering:  gacutil.exe -i "C:\YourAssemblyFileLocation\YourDLL.Dll"  That's all it takes. . .you don't normally need -r parameters, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to register assemblies into GAC. It doesn't need any specific installation.

Set-location "C:\Temp"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall("C:\Temp\myGacLibrary.dll")

If you need to get the name and PublicKeyToken, refer [How do I find the PublicKeyToken for a particular dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710935)